# Bootstrap modal open from php while result

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap modal is user friendly and I have put this in my php page.
In this page, I have a query and the result was send to php while variables.

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    while ($i < $rows) {
        $title_books=mysql_result($result,$i,"title_books");
        $pages_books=mysql_result($result,$i,"pages_books");
        $author_books=mysql_result($result,$i,"author_books");
?>
```

The dropdown-toggle, dislayed a drodown menu and inside there is a modal link. When Click on *Book in library* link, the modal do not open.

```
<div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalShareBk">Book in library</a> 
                <!-- inizio Box Modale Grande -->
                <div id="modalShareBk" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Your Books</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <?php include("inc_book.php"); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">
                                    <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Close
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: if you add `"onclick=$('#modalSharedBk').modal('show');"`, does it work?

Comment: Not work with this: <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalShareBk" onclick=$('#modalSharedBk').modal('show');>

Comment: You left out the quotation marks around the called script.  Please provide any console errors, too.

Comment: @Frankie it's opening, but it's hidden. Please see my answer for explanation.

Comment: Look at the answer below and notice the `z-index` setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your modal and place it outside of `ul.dropdown-menu`. Here are the styles for `.dropdown-menu` in `dropdowns.less`:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none; // <---- this is hiding your modal
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}
```

For example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-1">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalShareBk">Book in library</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- inizio Box Modale Grande -->
<div id="modalShareBk" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Your Books</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Your text will go here. We need information from you to replace this content. Please send us some information so we can update the text for you. Your text will go here. We need information from you to replace this content. Please send us some information so we can update the text for you. Your text will go here. We need information from you to replace this content. Please send us some information so we can update the text for you. Your text will go here. We need information from you to replace this content. Please send us some information so we can update the text for you. Your text will go here. We need information from you to replace this content. Please send us some information so we can update the text for you. Your text will go here. We need information from you to replace this content. Please send us some information so we can update the text for you. Your text will go here. We need information from you to replace this content. Please send us some information so we can update the text for you.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">
          <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```